# How to Access mysql and php cli in an xampp installation on linux?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp, command-line-interface

I installed xammp (php7) on my ubuntu machine. I want to access cli op PHP and MYSQL. Is there any workaround to do this?

OK Finally I found the answer . its by going to opt/lampp/bin/php

Comment: i did not start working on php7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK Finally I found the answer . its by going to opt/lampp/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

This appears as the first StackOveflow link in google search results so I'm leaving this here for future viewers.
Add `opt/lampp/bin` to PATH by adding the below line to `.bashrc`

```
export PATH="/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH"
```